# How to remove focus outline on clicked checkbox, but not keyboard focus?

Tags: css

In the example below, if you keyboard navigate to the checkbox, I get the custom focus state I'm looking for. However, I don't want the focus to show on click. I only want to show the focus state when it's keyboard navigated to.

**How do I remove the focus state if clicked on?**

```css
input[type=checkbox]:focus, input[type=checkbox]:focus-visible {
  outline: none;
}

label:focus-within {
  outline: 2px solid #005fec;
  outline-offset: 4px;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

```html
<label for="check1">
  <input type="checkbox" name="check1" id="check1">
  <span>Check Here</span>
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed it to the css solution, but I need to modify the html structure, take the input out of the lable, and modify the css like this

```css
input[type=checkbox]:focus, input[type=checkbox]:focus-visible {
  outline: none;
}

input[type=checkbox]:focus, input[type=checkbox]:focus-visible {
  outline: none;
}
/* I just added for here for debugging convenience, and now I have removed it
   label[for='check2']
 */
label{
  padding-left: 25px;
  margin-left: -25px;
}

input[type=checkbox]:focus-visible + label{
  outline: 2px solid #005fec;
  outline-offset: 4px;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="check2" id="check2">
<label for="check2">
    <span>Check Here2</span>
</label>
```

Comment: I shouldn't need JS to do this.

Comment: This is requiring that I add `for` attributes to my stylesheet. My site is a large site with hundreds of thousands of views and more than 500 pages. I can't accommodate that much custom CSS.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this!**

```css
input[type=checkbox], input[type=checkbox] {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<label for="check1">
  <input type="checkbox" name="check1" id="check1">
  <span>Check Here</span>
</label>
```

Comment: Did you look at the custom focus state I was looking for? The blue outline when it's focused on? You removed that and I don't understand why. I want the keyboard navigation focus state to remain the same... just not the clicked focus state. Please re-read my question.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid showing the outline on focus you have to use: `outline: none;` (https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/outline). In your case you have to add `outline: none;` only to the class `label:focus-within`.

```css
label:focus-within {
  outline: 2px solid #005fec;
  outline-offset: 4px;
  z-index: 10;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<label for="check1">
  <input type="checkbox" name="check1" id="check1">
  <span>Check Here</span>
</label>
```

Comment: I don't understand your answer. I have already achieved the outline design I want. I simply don't want that focus outline to appear when the label or the checkbox are clicked on. You removed the keyboard navigation in your suggestion. Please re-read the question.